# How can I get an argument name from argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

This is my command line script

```
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('My command line app')

parser.add_argument('--start', type=start, metavar='HOST', dest='result', nargs='*', default='all', help='Start hosts')
parser.add_argument('--stop', type=stop, metavar='HOST', dest='result', nargs='*', default='all', help='Stop hosts')
parser.add_argument('--status', type=status, metavar='HOST', dest='result', nargs='*', default='all', help='Show hosts status')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Currently I defined one function for each option, but I would like to wrap them in only one for these three options. Then I would need to know which argument was used. Is it possible with argparse?

**Solution**

At the end I took this way:

```
import argparse


def wrapper(command, hosts):
    pass


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('My script')
parser.add_argument('action', choices=['start', 'stop', 'status'], help='Action')
parser.add_argument('hosts', metavar='HOST', nargs='*', default='all')

args = parser.parse_args()

wrapper(args.action, args.hosts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the saner way to handle this would be the `choices` parameter:

```
commands = {'start': start, 'stop': stop, 'status': status}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('My command line app')
parser.add_argument('command', choices=commands.keys())
parser.add_argument('hosts', nargs='*', default=[])
args = parser.parse_args()

commands[args.command](*args.hosts)
```

Comment: And how can I get the list of hosts for the option: python commandline.py --status 44.44.44.44 55.55.55.55

Comment: I'd add them as a separate parameter, as updated above. This changes the CLI API to `my.py start foo bar baz` with only one possible command per invocation instead of multiple mixed commands right now, but this looks a lot saner to me.

Comment: I had to edit commands because I need only a wrapper for the three options, and at the end to add args.command as first functions argument. But really good your answer, thanks!